# Multiple IF and ELIF conditionals [Python]

Tags: python, if-statement

```
name="admin"
passw="aaa"

itemone="01"
itemtwo="02"

a=input("Enter your username:")
b=input("Enter your password:")

if(a==name)and(b==passw):
    print("Welcome.")
    c=int(input("Enter Item Code:"))

   if(c==itemone):
    print("Name: ID")
   elif(c==itemtwo):
    print("Name: Mirror")
   else:
    print("Item not found. Try again.")

else:
    print("Username/Password is incorrect.")
    exit()
```

## when "01" or "02" is entered, the program ignores all the other codes and directs to "item not found. try again."

## I finally got it to work! Thank you!!!

Comment: you are comparing c (an integer) to itemone (a string)

Comment: Please try and indent your code properly too so it's a bit easier to interpret!

Comment: You should use `raw_input` and not `input` as the later leads to your input string being `eval`ed see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score 3):

You are taking the input and casting it to an integer, then checking if it is equal to a string. This will return false. Example:

```
01=="01"
=> False

"01"=="01"
=> True
```

You don't need to cast the input to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

As robert_x44 said, you are comparing an integer with a string.

Try:

```
itemone=01
itemtwo=02
```

Also, in your post the if blocks are not indented. It is probably just a formatting error, but python if statements must be indented.

Answer (score 2):

Either change `itemone` and `itemtwo` to `int`s, or don't convert your input to an `int`. Right now you're comparing `int`s to `str`s, which won't work.

Pick one of the following two changes - don't make both or you'll just reverse the situation you're in now (comparing `str`s to `int`s instead of `int`s to `str`s.)

**How to use just `int`s**

Change:

```
itemone="01"
itemtwo="02"
```

to:

```
itemone=1
itemtwo=2
```

**How to use just `str`s**

Change:

```
c=int(input("Enter Item Code:"))
```

to:

```
c = input("Enter Item Code:")
```